# How to have sum function of a field of MB and GB values in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sum

My field values are like:

```
810.9 MB
1.2 GB
395.1 MB
982.3 MB
7.7 GB
149.4 MB
10.0 GB
429.1 MB
3.1 GB
```

and I want to sum this column in gb in my ASP.NET MVC controller.

But I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Seems like a horribly bad design idea to store **numerical** values of different "sizes" into a single column - combined with strings. You should store these things as **proper numbers** in the table - and only when you need to **show them** (on screen) should you format them with "MB" or "GB" or stuff like that. With such a setup, summing would be very very easy - with the current setup you have, it's a horrible hack/kludge at best ......

Comment: the values are coming from server,even if i make a function to remove strings how can i figure out that the value is mb or gb for suming function and displaying

Comment: do you have any idea for that?
for exaple changing values first and then get sum

Comment: Well, if you really only get these values from the server - all you can do is basically split the number and the "unit" up, and multiply the number by 1 million (for "mb") or 1 billion (for "gb") and then store the **numerical** values. Once you're doing that, you can easily just sum up those numerical values, and then present them on screen

Comment: i think its a good idea,i can do it in a foreach that do multiply for mb and gb with .endswith function 
but can you help me for doing the important part of that too?(split the number)
for example:
foreach(var item in list){
if item.datasize.endswith(mb){
doing split and multiply in here
}
}

Comment: Updated my response with a snippet of c# code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
-- This is your "raw" input - just all the strings in your example
DECLARE @input TABLE (Measure VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @input ( Measure )
VALUES ('810.9 MB'), ('1.2 GB'), ( '395.1 MB'), ( '982.3 MB'), ( '7.7 GB'), ( '149.4 MB'), ( '10.0 GB'), ( '429.1 MB'), ( '3.1 GB')

-- Now declare a separate table that contains (1) the raw value, (2) the contained *numerical* value, and (3) the unit of measure
DECLARE @Storage TABLE (Measure VARCHAR(50), NumValue DECIMAL(20,4), Unit VARCHAR(10))

-- Fill your raw input into that "working table"
INSERT INTO @Storage (Measure, NumValue, Unit)
    SELECT
        Measure,
        NumMeasure = CAST(SUBSTRING(Measure, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Measure)) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)),
        Unit = SUBSTRING(Measure, CHARINDEX(' ', Measure) + 1, 9999)
    FROM 
        @input

SELECT * FROM @Storage

-- when you select from that "working" table, you can now easily *SUM* the numerical values,
-- and show them on screen whichever way you want - as "xxx MB" or "yyyy GB" or whatever - up to you
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE Unit   
           WHEN 'MB' THEN NumValue * 1000000
           WHEN 'GB' THEN NumValue * 1000000000
           ELSE NumValue
        END),
    CAST(SUM(CASE Unit   
           WHEN 'MB' THEN NumValue * 1000000
           WHEN 'GB' THEN NumValue * 1000000000
           ELSE NumValue
        END) / 1000000000.0 AS VARCHAR(25)) + ' GB'
FROM 
    @Storage
```

**Update:**

If you want to do this in C# code, try this:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    // split "item" into two parts
    string[] parts = item.Split(' ');

    // parts[0] should be a decimal value
    decimal numValue = 0.0m;

    if (decimal.TryParse(parts[0], out numValue))
    {
        decimal convertedValue = 0.0m;

        if(parts[1] == "MB")
        {
            convertedValue = numValue * 1000000;
        }
        else if (parts[1] == "GB")
        {
            convertedValue = numValue * 1000000000;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks a million for your help
i tried to use it but there's an error,
Too many characters in character literal

Comment: @mohammadnaser: sorry - my bad - had been doing T-SQL all the time, so I used single quotes around the `MB` and `GB` strings - these need to be *double* quotes for C#

Comment: it's working just fine
you're awwwwwwesome
 thanks a Billion